What advantage do sinusoidal positional encodings have over binary positional encodings in transformer LLMs?
I've recently come across an article that discusses the reasons why large language models use sinusoidal functions to generate positional encodings — as per the famous paper Attention Is All You Need (page 6) — as opposed to simpler, more intuitive ways of encoding position, namely binary encoding, which simply takes the token's index's binary representation, stores it in a binary vector, and adds that to the word embedding.
The article begins by discussing the simplest way of encoding a token's position, concatenating the token's index to the word embedding, and outlines the problems the transformer would run into with this type of position encoding (unstable training due to large indices for long sequences).
The article points out a flaw with this binary encoding which I don't understand:

[A problem with binary encoding is that] our binary vectors come from a discrete function, and not a discretization of a continuous function.
[This] point is subtle, and it has to do with using a vector to represent a scalar position. Let’s compare two encodings, that try to measure a distance from 0 →3. The first encoding will be really simple: only use the x-axis dimension and put the position there, represented by a variable x in [0,3]. Continuous encoding: [x, 0].
Now let’s compare it to our binary vector discrete encoding. Since this is discrete, we can only represent 4 positions: 0, 1, 2, and 3. These give 4 points:
Binary vector encoding: [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1].
Any time we discretize something, we have inclination to believe that that something can be interpolated, meaning that we can construct a continuous function by connecting the dots. Take a look at the two interpolations for our two encodings:
--------------------The discrete curve (black) runs from (0,0)->(1,0)->(0,1)->(1,1), and is much more jagged than the smooth continuous curve (blue). You can see that the continuous encoding curve is smooth, and it’s easy to estimate intermediate positions. For the binary vector… that thing is a mess. This will lead us to our next hint: find a way to make the binary vector a discretization of something continuous.

This is where the article shows that we can make the binary vector a discretization of something continuous by replacing each bit in the binary vector with a sinusoid of analogous frequency.
My issue is this:
First of all, I don't see why we should be interested in being able to "estimate intermediate positions" when large language models exclusively deal with integer positions.
Second of all, a discretization of a continuous function is not necessarily more interpolable than a discrete function. This is especially clear in the first dimensions of sinusoidal positional embeddings, where the sinusoids are too high-frequency to suggest any kind of coherent underlying curve when discretized. See, the specific formula proposed here in the article for generating positional encodings is sin(2πi/2^j), where i is the respective token's position and j is the dimension of the positional encoding vector. If we take a close look at the first two dimensions, we can see that, for j=1, integer values of i always yield sin(2πi/2^1)=sin(πi)=0; for j=2, integer values of i yield {0, 1, 0, -1} cyclically. So far, these points do not seem more "interpolable" than discrete binary. The graph shown in the article to illustrate the interpolation from these points is misleading:

Since i must be an integer, in reality the model has a much sparser and more disjointed set of points to work with than the image suggests — namely, we are restricted to points with Dim 1 = 0 and Dim 2 ∈ {-1, 0, 1}. When you visualize this set of points, it's immediately clear that such a manifold can never be interpolated.
I have considered that this may all just be due to the author's sloppiness, and that it's easy to just scale down all the frequencies to get something more like what the previous graph suggests. However, what troubles me is that even the original Attention Is All You Need paper includes several very high-frequency sines that, when discretized, leave a set of points that are not only sparse, but erratically distributed because of the irrational frequencies.
So, to recap:
Why are we interested in being able to interpolate intermediate positions (if this is the reason binary encodings are insufficient) in the context of a large language model (where the only relevant positions are integers), and how is it any better to use discretized high-frequency sinusoids that seem impossible to interpolate from?

One property that distinguishes sinusoidal encoding from binary encoding is the following.
Let $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the encoding function.
Suppose $f$ is the sinusoidal encoding.
Then $f(a + b)$ is a linear function of $f(a)$.
As stated in the original paper:

We chose this function because we hypothesized it would allow the model to easily learn to attend by relative positions, since for any fixed offset $k$, $\text{PE}_{\text{pos}+k}$ can be represented as a linear function of $\text{PE}_{\text{pos}}$.

For example, suppose
\begin{align}
    f(a) = \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos a \\
        \sin a
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
    f(a + b) &= \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos (a + b) \\
        \sin (a + b)
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b \\
        \cos a \sin b + \sin a \cos b
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos b & -\sin b \\
        \sin b & \cos b
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos a \\
        \sin a
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    &= R(b) f(a)
\end{align}
where $R(b)$ is the rotation matrix for angle $b$.
A similar identity holds if $f(a)$ is replaced with $f(\omega a)$ for any $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.
In contrast, suppose $f$ is the binary encoding:
\begin{align}
    f(a)
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
        a \bmod 2 \\
        \lfloor a \div 2 \rfloor \bmod 2 \\
        \lfloor a \div 4 \rfloor \bmod 2 \\
        \lfloor a \div 8 \rfloor \bmod 2 \\
        \ldots
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then $f(a + 1)$ is not a linear function of $f(a)$.
Proof:
Let $e_i$ be the $i$th standard basis vector.
Then $f(1) = e_1$, which is not a linear function of $f(0) = 0$, since a linear function always maps zero to zero. $\blacksquare$

In fact, we can prove a stronger result: $f(a + 1)$ is not an affine function of $f(a)$.
Proof:
Suppose $f(a + 1)$ is an affine function of $f(a)$.
Then $f(a + 1) = M f(a) + c$ for some matrix $M$ and vector $c$.
Thus
\begin{align}
    f(1) &= M f(0) + c \\
    e_1 &= M 0 + c \\
    c &= e_1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
    f(2) &= M f(1) + c \\
    e_2 &= M e_1 + e_1 \\
    M e_1 &= e_2 - e_1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
    f(3) &= M f(2) + c \\
    e_1 + e_2 &= M e_2 + e_1 \\
    M e_2 &= e_2
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
    f(4) &= M f(3) + c \\
    &= M (e_1 + e_2) + e_1 \\
    &= M e_1 + M e_2 + e_1 \\
    &= e_2 - e_1 + e_2 + e_1 \\
    &= 2 e_2
\end{align}
But $f(4) = e_3 \neq 2 e_2$. Contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Why do we assume $f(0) = 0$ here. Shouldn't it be $f(0) = M*0 + c$

@CedricMartens $f(0)$ is the binary encoding of 0, which is the zero vector.
